# How can I integrate free google translate api with codeigniter without being blocked?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-translate

I'm trying to integrate Google translate Api with codeigniter at first it works but after few requests I'm getting this error `302 Moved` it seems like server blocked my ip address.

```php
<?php

class GoogleTranslate
{
    public static function translate($source, $target, $text)
    {

        $response = self::requestTranslation($source, $target, $text);         
        $translation = self::getSentencesFromJSON($response);
        return $translation;
    }

    protected static function requestTranslation($source, $target, $text)
    {       
        $url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=at&dt=t&dt=ld&dt=qca&dt=rm&dt=bd&dj=1&hl=es-ES&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&inputm=2&otf=2&iid=1dd3b944-fa62-4b55-b330-74909a99969e";

        $fields = array(
            'sl' => urlencode($source),
            'tl' => urlencode($target),
            'q' => urlencode($text)
        );

        $fields_string = "";
        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
            $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');       
        $ch = curl_init();       
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'AndroidTranslate/5.3.0.RC02.130475354-53000263 5.1 phone TRANSLATE_OPM5_TEST_1');
       $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
        protected static function getSentencesFromJSON($json)
    {
        $sentencesArray = json_decode($json, true);
        $sentences = "";

        foreach ($sentencesArray["sentences"] as $s) {
            $sentences .= isset($s["trans"]) ? $s["trans"] : '';
        }

        return $sentences;
    }
}
```

```php
$trans = new GoogleTranslate();
$result = $trans->translate($source, $target, $text);
```

I use an array containing many texts that should be translated.
How can I use Google translate Api without being blocked?

Comment: Why not start using the API instead of triggering a website request? https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/ holds a lot of documentation for that

Comment: A 302 doesn't usually mean you're blocked in the world of APIs.  If you're interested, google "restful api response codes".  You might want to see what data you get back from that 302.

Comment: @NicoHaase paid version

Comment: What do you mean by "paid version"? Sending a faked user agent and working without proper abstraction does not look good either

Comment: @CJones i got this message only `302 Moved The document has moved`
And there no data return [link](https://cloud.google.com/terms/service-terms#7-google-cloud-translation-api)

Comment: @NicoHaase it's just to show what i have tried.

Comment: So, where have you tried to access the official API in your code? Why not use the official client library for that?

Comment: It appears that a 302 is indeed a blocked IP when google detected a pile of requests that violate the Terms of Service.  You may need to look into a upgraded(pay for) version of translate.

Answer (score 4):

Use official Google Translate API, see https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

Each month Google give you 10$ credit for free. It means 500 000 translated characters per month for free.

Comment: But for how long?  Does that count in the 300$ offered the first year (will it stop after a year, or is it an unlimited offer?) . (Sorry to ask, I don't understand it in the google page `Free (applied as $10 credit)` https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing )

Comment: Every month you can use Translated API for up to $10 and you don't pay anything. Offered $300 credit is extra.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to create a function `translatetext()`

```
function translatetext($text){
    $curlSession = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=hi&dt=t&q='.urlencode($text));
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curlSession);
    $jsonData = json_decode($response);
    curl_close($curlSession);

    if(isset($jsonData[0][0][0])){
        return $jsonData[0][0][0];
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

$text = 'Kamla Nehru Nagar';

echo translatetext($text);

**Output: कमला नेहरू नगर**